# A Movie with Repopulation of Earth in Far Future

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am looking for a movie which ended when a group of young people emerge from a kind of spaceship in the far future where mankind had ceased to exist. The spaceship is a kind of intelligent spaceship (presumably with AI) which has used genetic technology to produce many babies that are also released from the space ship when it arrived in the future.

The young people emerging from the spaceship discover deformed bone, some with some kind of wings, from the past civilisation of humans. As I said this is the end of the movie.

I forgot a lot about the beginning of the movie. There was an older man, I suppose a scientist, who trained the young people in special abilities. For some reason this man died (or was left behind). One of the young people, a woman, had developed special abilities that allowed her to communicate with the space ship. Somehow the young people got trapped in the spaceship and sometimes the spaceship closed doors and sometimes it opened other doors.

I forgot how the spaceship arrived in the future. Presumably it left Earth with relativistic speed and when it returned to Earth a very long time has passed on Earth but only short time in the spaceship. But it could be also that the young people were put in stasis or that the spaceship had the possibility of time travel.

It is NOT the movie called *AE: Apocalypse Earth* (2013), it is also NOT the movie called *Millennium* (1989); as far as I remember I watched it around 1994 to 1998, but the movie could be also somewhat older.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an episode of the 1995-2002 run of *The Outer Limits*, specifically season 4 episode 23, [The Origin Of Species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Origin_of_Species_(The_Outer_Limits))

Fairly good description with the exception of it not being a movie, and the bones were not technically deformed; rather, they were from a genetically altered human.

Comment: Thank you very much for giving me the answer. I really looked for some time for it.

Comment: As I saw now it is Episode 23 of Season 4 of the 1995-2002 series "The Outer Limits", and it is a sequel to Episode 12 of Season 3 with the title "Double Helix", which should be watched first.

Comment: FYI, this series is on Hulu at this time. While this may seem a solicitation, I think it is free for the first month if you sign-up now. I did this very thing a few months ago with the sole purpose of watching every episode. Great series; many more episodes than I recalled watching when I was a pup.